# Type syntax for flow type declared module with class and static members

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm building a flow-type definition for Sequelize and have run into a small problem with the `declare` section of the flow-type.

Specifically  Sequelize generally is defined as:

```
class Sequelize {
    ....
}

Sequelize.DataTypes = DataTypes;
```

I can generate a flow-type declaration for either one but not both simultaneously. When I put DataTypes in a class they're member variables not available to the instantiated scope.

```
declare export default class sequelize$Class {
  constructor(...);
  DataTypes: sequelize$DataTypes;
}

declare var DataTypes: sequelize$DataTypes;
declare export var DataTypes;
```

Since I need to write code that looks like:

```
const db = new Sequelize(...)
const MyModel = db.define(... { email: { type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING } })
```

For the moment I've ended up putting this in place:

```
import Sequelize, { DataTypes } from "sequelize";
const sequelize: sequelize$Sequelize = ((new Sequelize(settings.database, { logging: false })): any);
```

There has to be a better way.

Comment: it would be very helpful if you could create a flow.org/try link with the code in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to give this a shot and let me know if it helps you out :)

You can declare the sequelize definition like so

```
declare module 'sequelize' {
  declare type sequelize$DataTypes = {
    STRING: string
  }

  declare export default class sequelize$Class {
    static DataTypes: sequelize$DataTypes;
    constructor(database: Object, options: Object): void;
  }

  declare export var DataTypes: sequelize$DataTypes;
}
```

This gives you a default export as well as a named export. I pre-define sequelize$DataTypes, pass it into sequelize$Class as a static property, and export it.